# Setting up jenkins slave/node global tools

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, master-slave

I am fairly new to CI.

I am receiving the following msbuild error when trying to run my build on Dobby (my other Windows slave/node):

```
FATAL: \msbuild.exe doesn't exist
```

However, my Master's Global Tools path is set to:

```
Name: MSBuild v4.5.1
Path to MSBuild: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```

And on Dobby under Configure --> Node Properties I've added the tool locations as written above.

My question is will Dobby be able to execute the MSBuild from the Master server's file location? Or would I need to add tools to the Jenkins Home --> tools location in order for it to be recognized globally?

Let me know if you have any questions, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then you would have to have the MSBuild set up on the node. When we set this up we used the absolute file path in the build. The code snippet below is from a Jenkinsfile (declarative pipeline) so we had to escape the backslashes.

`bat 'C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\msbuild .\\solution_file.sln'`

Typically with the master/agent setup in Jenkins you want to make sure the agent contains all of the information and tools necessary to handle the job.

Comment: Thanks Just_a_guy, this resolved my issue (along with some permissions adjustments). I thought that the Global installation would take care of the necessity to install MSBuild on the Slave/Node server but I guess that wasn't the case.